# CefSharp - How to implement Save As from Sources Tab of the developper Tools

Tags: c#, cefsharp

In Chrome Browser I open the developer tools, go to Sources Tab and open a JS File. Now I can right Click this File and click on save as. Now Chrome displays a Save as Dialog...

If I do the same in a CefSharp App nothing happens. So I guess that I have to implement it somehow. Can anybody point me into the right direction or to a sample?

Comment: What version are you using? `CEF` only just added support for saving of files in `DevTools`.

Comment: I use version 73.1.130

Comment: I see a dialog as expected, please provide more details.

Comment: If I create a new WPF project I also see the "Save as dialog" ...??? Well, I will find the problem. Thanks for your time. Just one thing: Actually I was hoping that I have to implement this and be able to save the file in my code to a special location without displaying the dialog. Is this possible?

Comment: No, not possible

Comment: Thinking about this further,  in the context of CEF there aren't any hooks into Devtools. You can access the raw response data and save it to disk using a response filter, there's an example of writing the data to a memory stream at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/30ee538ce0e0d1d33ed838665758ec2061165224/CefSharp.Example/Handlers/RequestHandler.cs#L225 the underlying CEF api is unfortunately a little complex. Might also be possible to enable remote debugging and use puppeteer Sharp or similar, haven't looked into this in any detail, just a thought..

Comment: I don't want to chat here… If you want to know more about the background of my question contact me over email. (to find my mail address go: so-profile - my website - Impressum - Kontakt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved in the newest Version (73.1.130) of Cefsharp. My project was using an older version. I cleaned up all references and rebuild the nuget packages. Now it works.